# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Shallow Copy y Deep Copy?

Tags: javascript

A lo largo del aprendizaje de Javascript, he leído terminologías como *Shallow Copy* y *Deep Copy*, y me surgió la siguiente pregunta:

¿Cuál es la verdadera diferencia entre *Shallow Copy* (Copia Superficial) y *Deep Copy* (Copia Profunda)?

```js
const moderador = {
  nombre : "Gbianchi", 
  lenguajesFavoritos : ["JavaScript", "Java","PHP"],
  esDesarrollador : true, 
  fechaNacimiento : "2010/01/01"
}

const persona = Object.assign({}, moderador);
persona.nombre = "PabloLozano"
persona.esDesarrollador = false;
persona.lenguajesFavoritos.push("PHP7");

console.info("moderador", moderador );

console.info("persona", persona)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si representas un objeto como un grafo, tendrás un árbol donde en cada nodo tienes una propiedad de dicho objeto. Esas propiedades a su vez pueden ser objetos, con lo que la profundidad del árbol crece.

Empecemos con un objeto simple:

```
const obj1 = {
  A: 1
  B: 2
}
```

Tiene dos propiedades que guardan valores primitivos, por lo que si copiáramos el objeto a otro:

```
const obj2 = {
  A : obj1.A,
  B : obj1.B
}
```

Habríamos "clonado" el objeto y no nos tendríamos que preocupar de nada, ya que los valores primitivos son inmutables.

Pero ¿qué pasa si `obj1` tiene como propiedad un objeto? ¿O si esta propiedad tiene a su vez otras propiedades que son objetos?:

```
const obj1 = {
  A: 1,
  B: { deep: [0,1,2] }
};

const obj2 = {
  A : obj1.A,
  B : obj1.B
};

obj2.B.deep[0] = 3;

¡Estaríamos modificando el objeto obj1!
```

Esto se considera una copia poco profunda, porque no replicamos cada uno de los valores guardados de manera recursiva: nos hemos parado en el primer nivel de profundidad.

El peligro de la copia "poco profunda" es encontrarnos con este tipo de efectos colaterales al modificar propiedades de un objeto, mientras pensamos que otro objeto es totalmente independente de lo que estamos haciendo.

Pero hacer una copia profunda puede ser:

- **Costoso**: si la profundidad del objeto a copiar es grande.
- **Complejo**: si en realidad no tenemos un árbol, sino un grafo con ciclos. En este caso un algoritmo mal diseñado o que no espera esta estructura puede acabar en un bucle infinito o en un stack overflow por exceso de recursividad. Además, algunas de las propiedades pueden ser funciones (métodos) que podrían comportarse de un modo extraño al cambiarles el contexto (this).

Por eso, cuando hacemos una copia de un objeto, hemos de elegir qué tipo de copia necesitamos hacer. Una llamada a **[`Object.assign(A, B)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)** copia a A todas la propiedades existentes en B, con lo que nos da una copia "*poco profunda*" de un modo sencillo. Para hacer una copia más profunda necesitaríamos de una funcionalidad más compleja, en la que quizá podamos elegir la profundidad de la copia a realizar y si queremos copiar funciones.
Si el objeto es profundo pero no tiene ciclos ni funciones, podemos usar

```
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Pero esto fallará en caso de encontrarse con ciclos:

```js
const obj3 = {
  p1: 'A',
  p2: 1
}

obj3.p3= obj3;

JSON.stringify(obj3);
```